# Android MenuItemCompat.getActionView is Deprecated

Tags: android, menu, deprecated

I am implementing a SearchView like this:

```
    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
```

But this gives me an inspection report

> 'getActionView(android.view.MenuItem)' is deprecated

Now in the docs, it is mentioned:

> This method was deprecated in API level 26.0.0
>
> Use getActionView() directly.

So I tried this:

```
    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) getActionView(search);
```

But it still gives me the deprecated message. So what is the best practice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getActionView is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306133/getactionview-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try:

```
MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search.getActionView();
```

[getActionView is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306133/getactionview-is-deprecated)